# Compute the length of a longest common substring of two given 0 - 1 strings

Tags: c++

Full title:

> "Compute the length of a longest common sub-string  of two given 0 - 1 strings. Input format has at least two test cases, each consisting of two non-empty 0-1 strings of lengths at most 100.The input terminates on `EOF`"

Here is one of my Homework, I did found out the way to compute the length of a longest common sub-string of two given 0-1 strings but I don't know how to input many test cases at ones.
Please help me if you guys have any solution for this problem.

This is my code :

```
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
string A,B; 
int lcs(int i, int j, int count) 
{ 
if (i == 0 || j == 0) 
return count; 
if (A[i-1] == B[j-1]) 
{ 
count = lcs(i - 1, j - 1, count + 1); 
}
count = max(count, max(lcs( i, j - 1, 0), lcs( i - 1, j, 0))); 
return count; 
}

int main() 
{ 
int n,m; 
cout << "Input String A and B \n"; 
cin >> A; cin >> B; 
n=A.size(); 
m=B.size(); 
cout<< "Longest common substring "<< lcs(n,m,0) << endl; 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you already have?

Comment: Here one of my version of Code that I have submit but get reject because It only can input 2 . :

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
  
string A,B;
int lcs(int i, int j, int count)
{
      
    if (i == 0 || j == 0)
        return count;
          
    if (A[i-1] == B[j-1]) {
        count = lcs(i - 1, j - 1, count + 1);
    }
        count = max(count, max(lcs( i, j - 1, 0), lcs( i - 1, j, 0)));
    return count;
}
 
int main()
{
int n,m;
  
cout << "Input String A and B \n";
cin >> A;
cin >> B;
  
n=A.size();
m=B.size();
  
cout<< "Longest common substring "<< lcs(n,m,0) << endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Please update your question iso posting it as a comment

Comment: @KohaDing Please put this into the question, it's hardly readable in the comments :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I just got back from my part time job. I have edit the title again. Tks

Answer (score -1):

```
int solveYourProblemFunc(string str1, string str2) {
/* your code */
}

int main() {
   int testCount;
   cin >> testCount;
   vector<int> results;
   while(testCount--) {
    string str1, str2;
    getline(cin, str1);
    getline(cin, str2);
    int res = solveYourProblemFunc();
    results.push_back(res);
   }
  /* output results  */
}
```

Comment: there's no `testCount`, just the strings, then file ends (=EOF).

Comment: when i answered about EOF was no word)